# Is there any way we can shortn the Presigned URL with I AM ROLE on AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, symfony, aws-lambda, pre-signed-url

We are getting presigned url too long almost 1600-1800 character with "I AM ROLE", that not fair. It's has an impact on API response size, like if a API have 2,3 pre-signed URL it's sizes goes to 3 times greater (in term of size) than previous one.

If we were getting pre-resigned URL from AWS Key and Secret that size within 400-500 character range, AS we move on AWS IAM Role then it's sizes greater 3 times.
Is there any way to shorten the Presigned URL, without compromise the API response or can say solution should be optimized that most important?

By using PHP (7.4) & Symfony framework (v 3.4) ...

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68562310/how-to-shortened-presignedurl-of-s3-file-in-spring-boot

Comment: It is likely that scripts, includes and CSS sheets are using much more bandwidth than a few URLs.

Answer (score 0):

The URL can not be shortened.

There is a workaround though: you could create a short URL "service" yourself that translates your short URLs to the presigned URLs.

```
https://example.org/123 -> https://s3....
```

But in the end, I would not bother with the response size of your API. If you use compression like gzip I don't think that the response size should be a concern.

Comment: In this way, I have to save the these keys  like 123 in database and then redirect take some time, I tried that also have a cost @jens